# How can I get the gameplay videos from Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

I try to put them on a USB, but  I can't figure out how to get them on to it. I couldn't find anything useful when I did a Google search.

Comment: You may be able to find them [here](http://xboxdvr.com/).

Comment: You say you didn't find anything helpful in a Google search - what did you find? What did you try?

Comment: Do you have a Windows 10 PC?

Comment: @Childishforlife Please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Windows 10 PC and the Xbox app installed. You simply navigate over to the Game DVR menu.

[image: game dvr]

Click "On Xbox Live"

[image: on xbox live]

Select the video you wish to download.

[image: desired video]

Click download.

[image: download video]

Type `Windows Key+R` type in `%userprofile%\Videos\Captures\` this will give you the folder in which the files are saved.